# ListView scrollbar messes up my layout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF ListBox that typically shows 4 or 5 items. For my application that means I almost never have to display a scrollbar (there is enough space).

However, in case there are more items in the list, I need to show the vertical scroll bar, but as a  result my content has less space and doesn't look nice anymore on a "backdrop" I've created behind the listbox.

I like to "reserve" room in my layout for the scrollbar to appear. Is there a way to do that? (maybe having the scrollbar overlayed on the content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found a solution.

I've created a new default style for the ScrollViewer by following [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771748.aspx).  Then I've changed the part where the scrollbars are placed.

*Original behaviour*

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="True" Content="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.Content}" />
  </Border>
  <ScrollBar Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight}" Value="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight}" Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
  <ScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth}" Value="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth}" Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
</Grid>
```

*New behaviour*

```
<Grid>
  <!-- Presentation below is different from the default: the scrollbar is overlayed on the content. -->
  <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="True" Content="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.Content}" />
  <ScrollBar Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight}" Value="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight}" Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
  <ScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth}" Value="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth}" Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now the scrollbars are overlayed on the content so they don't take additional space when visible. Of course the content should now reserve space for the content.

Comment: The downside of this is that the scrollbars will appear on top of the content and possibly obscure some of it.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping it with a ScrollViewr?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<!-- your ListBoxHere -->           
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem, the scrollbar still takes space

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, you just need to reserve the width for the vertical scrollbar, following XAML code will give you some idea.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid> 
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/> <!-- reserved for the vertical scrollbar -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Listbox .../>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```